# Cannot remove an item after back button is pressed

Tags: redux

I'm working with Redux in my country app project and whenever I press the back button and try to remove some saved comparable countries, it does not do anything.

Here is a gif representation:

[image]

As you can see in the gif representation, I checkmark a total of 5 countries and remove 2 (on the same screen) which works fine. But when I press the *Compare* button and remove *Albania* for example, the country is not removed.

I went to the Redux Dev Tools for Google Chrome and it read that the remove action is unchanged (same state) and I don't know why it's doing this.

Here is my code:

Flags reducer

```
const flagsInitialState = {
    compare: false,
    compareCountries: [],
    countryChecked: new Map()
}

export default ( state = flagsInitialState, action ) => {
    switch( action.type ) {
        case 'COMPARE_MODE':
            return {
                ...state,
                compare: ! state.compare
            }
        case 'ADD_COUNTRY_TO_COMPARE':
            return {
                ...state,
                compareCountries: [ ...state.compareCountries, action.country ]
            }
        case 'REMOVE_COUNTRY_TO_COMPARE': // <-- This is the action that does not remove an item when the back button is pressed
            return {
                ...state,
                compareCountries: state.compareCountries.filter( compareCountry => compareCountry !== action.country )
            }
        case 'SET_COUNTRY_MAPPING':
            return {
                ...state,
                countryChecked: state.countryChecked.set( action.name, action.checked )
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Flags actions

```
export const switchCompareMode = () => ({
    type: 'COMPARE_MODE'
})

export const addCountryToCompare = country => ({
    type: 'ADD_COUNTRY_TO_COMPARE',
    country
})

export const removeCountryToCompare = country => ({
    type: 'REMOVE_COUNTRY_TO_COMPARE',
    country
})

export const setCountryMapping = ( name, checked ) => ({
    type: 'SET_COUNTRY_MAPPING',
    name,
    checked
})
```

CountriesPage.jsx

```
const onCompareClick = ( country, e ) => {
        const checked = e.target.checked
        const name = e.target.name
        props.dispatch( setCountryMapping( name, checked ) )
        if ( props.countryChecked.get( name ) ) {
            props.dispatch( addCountryToCompare( country ) )
        } else {
            props.dispatch( removeCountryToCompare( country ) )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check what is your `action.country` in the filter function in reducer.

Comment: Yes, I just did a log of `action.country` and it returns the correct country index.

Comment: `compareCountry` is not index, it is country, so your `action.country` should be the actual country instead of the index

Comment: Yes, sorry I phrased my answer wrong. I meant to say that I did receive the country _object_ from `action.country`. I just don't understand why it works fine when I'm on the screen itself and when I press the back button to remove other ones in the array, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After much thinking, I finally came around fixing it! I just needed to compare the country name *strings* rather than the country *objects*.

```
case 'REMOVE_COUNTRY_FROM_COMPARE':
  return {
    ...state,
    compareCountries: state.compareCountries.filter( compareCountry => compareCountry.name !== action.country.name )
  }
```

Thanks for the help anyway guys!